# How to derive a context which can be used after an inbound request has ended?

Tags: go

From the documentation of `func (r *Request) Context() context.Context` in the `net/http` package:

> For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2), or when the ServeHTTP method returns.

What is the correct thing to do if I want to complete work related to the request after the `ServeHTTP` method has returned, for example emitting notifications? I'd like to preserve the context chain in terms of values but simply passing the context originally returned by the above method to the message queue submission API doesn't work as the context may be cancelled before it completes.

Is there an easy way to derive just the values in a context chain without deadline or cancellation? I can manually copy values I have the keys for, but other things that rely on context continuity, like trace, will be absent.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Use a separate context for cancelling separate operations, and try to store less data in the context. Context's primary purpose is cancellation, and it is suboptimal as a general-purpose key-value store.

Comment: Context values are intended for request scoped data. If you have stuff in there that you need after the request ends it's obviously not request scoped and a big red flag. Consider passing these things around separately.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to derive just the values?

Out of the box, no.  There are two possibilities I can imagine:

1. You could make a custom context, that swallows/ignores cancellations. Such a type would need a custom implementation of `Done()` and `Err()`, which detected a timeout/cancellation, and ignored it.

   This approach has a possible drawback, that you may be referencing values which are expected to go out of scope at the end of a request. This could lead to race conditions or other data integrity issues.

   I would advise against this method, although it's probably the closest to what you're asking for. Contexts should be used primarily for cancellation, so heavy use of values in context is an anti-pattern.
2. Probably the safer and easier solution, to which you eluded in your question, would be to explicitly copy any values you still care about to a new context created with `context.Background()`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer @Flimzy. I had already gone for option 2 but it's nice to get a second opinion from a more authoritative source (going on SO rep!).

In case anyone's interested, to try to keep my traces working (I am using https://godoc.org/go.opencensus.io/trace), I will be exploring just manually starting a span as the async operation is started.